# Proper padding for nested elements with Susy 2

Tags: susy-sass

I am trying to build a simple nested layout with Susy 2: A container with two columns (children), with each child column containing copy and two nested columns (grandchildren).

I am noticing that the grandchildren columns have their own gutters and thus their content does not align with the gutters of their parent.

Ideally, the grandchildren (and their background colors) would extend to the full-width of the child element.

What is the best approach to achieve this?

gist: https://gist.github.com/andreimoment/2a734aa4a0e99b2866e9

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>child 1</p>
    <div class="grandchild">Grandchild 1</div>
    <div class="grandchild last">Grandchild 2</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="child last">child 2</div>  
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
@import "compass";
@import "susy";

*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}

$susy: (
  columns: 12,
  column-width: 4em,
  gutters: 1/4,
  math: fluid,
  output: float,
  gutter-position:inside,
  global-box-sizing: border-box,
  debug: (
    image: show,
    color: rgba(200,100,100,.3),
    output: overlay,
    toggle: top right,
  ),
);

.parent {
  @include container();
  @include show-grid(background);
  padding:0;
  @include clearfix;
  }

.child {
  background-color: rgba(100,100,200, 0.5);
  @include span(first 6 of 12);
  &.last {
    @include span(last 6 of 12);
  }
}

.grandchild {
  background-color: rgba(100,100,200, 0.5);
  @include span(first 3 of 6);
  &.last {
    @include span(last 3 of 6);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `nest` keyword to tell Susy that a span has children. This is only needed with `inside` and `split` gutters — which you are using.

```
@include span(first 6 of 12 nest);
```

You can also use `no-gutters` any time you want Susy to not output gutters — but `nest` is the more semantically clear in this case.

NOTE: you also don't need to use `first` with `inside` or `split` gutters. You don't *need* `last` either, but it can help with some sub-pixel rounding issues. Those aren't hurting anything, but you can drop them without causing damage.

Comment: Thank you, Eric. Am I correct in my understanding that adding "nested" produces gutters with consistent size given that I use correct context for the child/grandchild elements?

Comment: Are you talking about the `nest` keyword I mentioned, or the `nested` mixin that we also provide? I'm not sure I understand the question. If you use context correctly, gutters should remain consistent even in nested locations. The `nest` keyword makes sure you don't double-up on the edges, and the `nested` mixin helps you manage context for larger blocks.

Comment: I meant the nested keyword, and you answered my question. Thanks!

Comment: `Use the nest keyword to tell Susy that a span has children` - why would a span wouldn't have children? I still miss the point of "nest"

Comment: `nest` removes `inside` or `split` gutters on a parent element, so those gutters don't get duplicated by the child. Only important if the child elements are also being laid out on the grid using susy.

Comment: @EricMSuzanne If I understand correctly, the `nest` keyword always removes gutters on both sides. But suppose you're using split gutters and you apply `@include span(first 6 of 12 nest);` to an element, wouldn't it make sense if the element does get half a gutter on the right side?

Comment: With split gutters we don't worry at all about `first` and `last` — that's the entire advantage. If we always apply the gutters together, at the deepest level of nesting, it's much simpler.